# Remix IDE not connecting to Ganache Web3 Provider

Tags: remix, ganache, web3-providers, ganache-cli

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract to Ganache (perferably the Ganache desktop app but this issue is also occurring for ganache-cli). When I select "Web3 Provider" under the "Environment" tab in Remix IDE, and put in the Web3 Provider Endpoint, I get the following error:

```
Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running, a connection is open (via IPC or RPC) or that the provider plugin is properly configured.
```

I get this error when using the default endpoint of 'http://127.0.0.1:8545' while running ganache-cli and with 'http://127.0.0.1:7545' as the endpoint while running the ganache desktop app. I confirmed both of these addresses are being used by ganache-cli and the desktop app from the terminal. I am already running remix with http://remix.ethereum.org and **NOT** on https, since this seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Can you check for errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the remix IDE from here https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases and try to connect again.

Hope it helps :)